# JQuery make input number negative

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-2

We have this textbox:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FloatingComponent.IndexOptions.Lookbackdays, new { @class = "economicTextBox DontShrinkBigger", propertyName = "FloatingComponent.IndexOptions.Lookbackdays" })%>
```

I want the functionality to be this:

1. If a user enters a positive number, I want JQuery to add a negative sign before it,
2. If they input a negative number, don't do anything.

How can I do that with JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maths behind it is quite simply `0 - int`. To update the field:

```
$('input').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() > 0) {
         $(this).val(0 - $(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: @slandau: Then use `$('selector').val(input)`.

Comment: Won't this only work in firefox/chrome. I thought using selectors as variables didnt work in IE

Comment: Ok updated answer, obviously 'selector' will have to be something that references your textbox, but you haven't supplied that info.

Comment: Put the textbox html in the answer and I'll tell you the selector

Comment: "I thought using selectors as variables didnt work in IE" Huh?

Comment: ^^ Not sure about that comment! Updated my answer to contain the jQuery needed to change the input when it changes.

Answer (score 4):

not really fluent in js but i'm guessing something along the lines of

```
if (x > 0){
x = x - (x*2)
}
else 
{ do nothing }
```

Comment: This *will* negate a number, but it's the oddest way that I've seen.  Most people would use `-1*x` or `0-x`.

Comment: Question asked for JQuery, so this *needs more JQuery*:
`$.each({"_x": x, "_another_x": x}, function( key, value ) {
  x = x - value;
});`

Answer (score 4):

**Without an if:**

```
var input = 0 - Math.abs($('selector').val());
```

**Why it works**

`Math.abs()` will convert any number into a positive one, IE, `-4` turn to `4`, `12` stays the same etc etc.

Now we have made our input to be a positive number, we negative it by subtracting it from 0.